# Can't compile my C program on my raspberry Pi using multithreading

Tags: c, raspberry-pi, pthreads, linker-errors, undefined-reference

I can't link pthread to my program. I tried `gcc Tracker.c -lpthread -lwiringPi` and only get `undefined reference to pthread_creat`. I tried to use `-lpthread` and `-pthread`. I also can't find a solution on the internet.

Comment: While there is a function called `creat`, it's for creating files. Creating threads is done with [`pthread_create`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html) (note trailing `e`).

Comment: Well shit. I knew ist was something stupid. Sorry

Comment: With no declaration of *pthread_creat* you should get an error from the compiler, before the error from the linker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `undefined reference to pthread_creat`

The function to create a POSIX-Thread is called [`pthread_create()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_create.html).